# How do a ball bounce in air?

Tags: free-fall

An unclear case happened in Fenerbahce-Galatasaray football match last night. Galatasaray's striker Burak Yilmaz hit the ball when he was front of goalkeeper. Something happened while ball in free fall, it bounced in air and went out. What are the factors that might caused this?

[image: Free Fall Bounce]

Vine video: https://vine.co/v/OEwjqZOX9hB

Comment: Personally I don't see the bounce in the video, but I'll take your word for it. The [Magnus effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) is responsible for this sort of behaviour.

Comment: @lemon - it's there... as the timer goes from 10:38 to 10:39. It looks much too sudden to be Magnus effect. As though there's a wire (field camera?) strung across the field, and the ball bounced off it. But usually those would be a little bit higher to stay away from the play, obviously.

Comment: @Floris I still don't see it. The camera pans down at that particular moment which certainly gives the *illusion* that the ball has bounced up...

Comment: @lemon - you are right. When you look at the background, the camera changes (abruptly) from panning up to panning down/across, and the ball appears to "bounce" as a result. It's an optical illusion. Please write it as an answer and I will give you an upvote.

Comment: Frankly, I see no indication of any unusual motion (bounce or otherwise) in the linked video.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no indication that the ball bounces.

Answer (score 6):

It appears to be an optical illusion. If you look at the background, the camera actually pans down when the ball appears to jerk up.

In general though, the trajectory of a ball can change while moving through the air due to the interaction of the spin of the ball with the air-flow. This is the so-called [Magnus effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect).

Comment: Good eye. Optical illusion it is.